# can't play srf.ch video content (official TV channel from Switzerland regime)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

example URL

```
http://www.srf.ch/sport/tennis/wta-tour/wildcards-en-masse-fuer-scharapowa-zurecht#
```

When I click on the video, it just opens a new tab with the same page.

[image]

why this is prevented by TBB on macOS? Those videos a privacy violation? It seems not flash, because I can play it on mobile device.

Comment: I get an error from their player "app", so js is probably erroring out: `TypeError: b.style is undefined` I don't know .js well enough to debug it itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their app requires javascript to stream the segments.  Eg:
https://hdvodsrforigin-f.akamaihd.net/i/vod/sport_clip/2016/12/sport_clip_20161216_090437_v_webcast_h264_,q40,q10,q20,q30,q50,q60,.mp4.csmil/segment7_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28

They could hypothetically be downloaded and watched in VLC, but you'd need to write a script, and deal with whatever captchas / anti-DDOS setup they have, so not worth it probably.

Here is a partial list of segments I got from Chrome:

`segment7_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment4_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment10_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment12_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment9_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment2_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment5_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment6_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment11_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment3_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment8_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28
segment13_5_av.ts?start=0&end=129.28`